# CompletableFuture chaining with exception handling

Tags: java, completable-future

I am trying to compose a chain of steps such that I can avoid a large nested chain of `if` and `else` calls by creating methods that return `CompletableFuture<Boolean>` in a manner such as....

```
client.connect(identifier).thenCompose(b -> client.authenticate())
                           .thenCompose(b -> client.sendSetting(settings))
                           .thenCompose(b -> client.saveSettings())
                           .thenCompose(b -> client.sendKey(key))
                           .thenCompose(b -> client.setBypassMode(true))
                           .thenCompose(b -> client.start())
                           .whenComplete((success, ex) -> {
                                 if(ex == null) {
                                     System.out.println("Yay");  
                                 } else {
                                     System.out.println("Nay");   
                                 }
                           });
```

If the client methods return a `CompletableFuture<Boolean>` deciding whether to continue processing has to be done in each lambda in the chain and doesn't provide a method to abort early if one of the calls fail. I would rather have the calls return `CompletableFuture<Void>` and use `Exceptions` to control if 1) each successive step in the chain executes and 2) final determination of success of the full chain.

I am having trouble finding which method on `CompletableFuture<Void>` to swap for `thenCompose` to make things work (let alone compile).

Comment: Also note my chain of calls is 8 steps in length.

Comment: Please post realistic code, it's hard to figure out what the challenge is or even to understand what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @ernest_k thanks for the input. Hopefully this iteration of the question is more clear.

Comment: Are you doing anything asynchronous? And where do `settings`, `key` come from? Are they local-scoped variables?

Comment: Yes each of the client calls requires IO over the serial port. Yes the variables are locally scoped.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FutureChaings {
    public static CompletableFuture<Void> op(boolean fail) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
        System.out.println("op");
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(() -> {
            if(fail) {
                future.completeExceptionally(new Exception());
            }
            future.complete(null);          
        }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

        return future;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        op(false).thenCompose(b -> op(false)).thenCompose(b -> op(true)).whenComplete((b, ex) -> {
            if(ex != null) {
                System.out.println("fail");
            } else {
                System.out.println("success");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I was able to contrive an example that behaved the way I wanted. So I know what calls to put together to get what I want. Now to figure out what the compiler doesn't like in my real code. Thanks for the comments.